# scala scope and pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
case class Thing(n: Int)
def ThingCreator(c:Int): Thing = 
{
    val a = 10
    val b = 20
    c match {
        case 0 => Thing(1)
        case a => Thing(2)
        case b => Thing(3)
        case _ => Thing(4)
    }
}
```

What would be the output if we call ThingCreator() with inputs ranging from 0 to 100?

The answer was given as `Thing(1) and Thing(2)` but I don't get how it is not `Thing(1) through Thing(4)`. If we pass 50 it should match the last case. Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: for **lowercase** in **pattern match**, it means  it's a variable, you should use ``a`` for match the value.

Answer (score 0):

`case x`, where `x` is any lowercase identifier, matches any value and assigns it to a newly created variable named `x`.

This is true regardless of whether or not a variable with the same name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thats becuase *Scala compiler* will never go below the `case a => Thing(2)` line in your *match case pattern*

*Scala compiler* should throw a warning

```
patterns after a variable pattern cannot match (SLS 8.1.1)
    case a => Thing(2)
         ^
```

and

```
unreachable code
case b => Thing(3)
               ^
```

And *SLS 8.1.1* states

> > A variable pattern x is a simple identifier which starts with a lower case letter.   It matches any value, and binds the variable name to that value.  The type of x is the expected type of the pattern as given from outside.  A special case is the wild-card pattern _ which is treated as if it was a fresh variable on each occurrence.